# What has strtok been replaced with?

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

**I am trying to split a string into words**, similar to what you get in argc + argv[] in C's main function.

**I do not want to use strtok** because I read here some weeks ago that there is a better, easier to use alternative.

I cannot find the better alternative after a bit of googling, even though I do remember reading about it here on stackoverflow - one of the answers provided a way of "tokenizing" a string using the newer, better function.

**Expected results:**

input:
"this is my string"

output:
["this","is","my","string"]

(Please note that I am not asking how to split the string into words, I am asking what's the name of the new alternative to strtok)

Edit: At the risk of beign wrong, I won't answer my own question, so here's a link that talks about **strsep**, an apparent substitute to strtok. Can anyone confirm that this is the case?

https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1769

Edit 2: For the love of god, THE QUESTION LINKED as the original to this """duplicate""" isn't the same, and NONE of the answers in that question mention **strsep**. Stackoverflow being stackoverflow. For future readers from google that actually read the whole question, ignore the linked "original" above.

Comment: `strtok_r()` from posix, maybe? Or `strtok_s()` on Windows?

Comment: @Broman
It's not a duplicate. I just found what I was looking for, though!
https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1769

Comment: `strsep` is not part of the C standard, so it will not be fully portable, but if it is available to you, it would be a good option.

Comment: Instead of using `strtok` which has side effects on the string and is neither reentrant nor thread safe, use the standard functions `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to compute the offsets and the lengths of the substrings.